# CSS - Inheritance of opacity value with DIV inside DIV

Tags: css

How can I prevent the opacity level on the parent DIV from becoming the limit for the child DIV?

```
 <div style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; opacity: .50; z-index: 1000; background-color:red;">
                            <div style="opacity:1; margin-top:25%; color:white;">
                                <apex:pageMessages />    
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Right now the child DIV will only go to a max of 50%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rgba` for the background color of the parent (*and remove the opacity property completely*). This allows to set transparency to the background color only, and not the actual element.

So instead of

```
background-color:red;
```

use

```
background-color:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
```

Comment: Good work around. For the sake of explaining *why* this is, I'll point out the reason that there's a max is that *opacity is multiplied as it's applied to descendants:* if the parent has an opacity of 0.5 and the child has an opacity of 1 that still results in 0.5 × 1 = 0.5.